# Webform for marketer send email action issue with List Types

Tags: wffm

I got an issue with sending the email action of `WFFM`. The send email action works fine with the form that doesn't have a field with List type. When I change or add a field to the List type, the send mail action doesn't work.

There are no error logs. The form submission is successful.
I'm using `Sitecore 8.1 & WFFM 8.1`

Comment: is it happening with a new form or after updating the existing form?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat Hi, it happens with new form and updating the existing form. Luckily, I figure out it is a bug from WFFM. I just updated the patch follow ing this instruction then the issue has been resolved ^^
https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.67086/releases